# I need a regular expression that will deal with apostrophes when extracting words from text

Tags: python, regex, text-parsing

Anybody know a way of dealing with apostrophes when extracting words from text using a regular expression?

```
>>> import re
>>> s = re.compile(r"\b[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+\b")
>>> s.findall("I don't know Sally's 'special' friend.")
['I', 'don', 't', 'know', 'Sally', 's', 'special', 'friend']
```

Desired result:

```
['I', "don't", 'know', 'Sally', 'special', 'friend']
```

[This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717886/extracting-whole-words/32301537#32301537) covers how to find whole words but doesn't deal with apostrophes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28058612/1400768

Answer (score 3):

```
s = re.compile(r"(?:^|(?<=\s))[A-Za-z0-9_'\-]+(?=\s|$|\b)")
```

Use this instead of `\b`.`lookarounds` will work for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/25

Comment: Thanks.  That produces a result that is pretty close: `['I', "don't", 'know', "Sally's", "'special'"]`

Comment: Although it loses the last word ('friend')!

Comment: @Bill https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/26 now it wont lose